# Class method performance test during execution

Tags: python, timeit

I have a class that contains a methodT to be used by another class methodM, and I want to time the run time of methodT.

Here are the things I've tried

```
Class MyClass(threading.Thread):
    def __init__():
       threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run_porcess(self, args)
       # start a subprocess and print output

    def run(self):
       # ==========================================
       # method A:
       # ==========================================
       start_time = time.clock()
       self.run_process('args')
       elapsed = time.clock() - start_time
       print(elapsed)

       #===========================================
       # method B:
       #===========================================
       timeit.timeit('self.run_process("args")')
```

With method A, I can get an result, but I believe it is a less accurate one compared to one that timeit gives.

However, with method B, timeit will produce an NameError as it doesn't recognize self.run_process

I've read the [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3609148/python-timeit-within-a-class) post, and tried adding the timewrapper method

```
def timewrapper(args)                       
     return self.run_process(args)
```

it just doesn't work for me as it gives a `NameError: global name 'timewrapper' is not defined`.

My question is how do I correctly implement the method B using timeit?

NOTE: I cannot use modules other than core python

Answer (score -1):

What version of python are you using? In version 3.3 [`time.clock()` is deprecated](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/time.html#time.clock) and it is recommended you use `perf_counter()` or `process_time()`. That could contribute to the inaccuracy.

Comment: Im using 2.7, which doesn't have perf_counter or process_time. Also, I would prefer to use timeit